# Integrating phpPgAdmin to XAMPP throws errors

Tags: php, postgresql, xampp, phppgadmin

I installed Postgre with Xampp 7.2.1. Postgre Database. The database just works just fine, but I`m having trouble getting phpPgAdmin to work.
I downloaded phpPgAdmin from here:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/phppgadmin/
I followed the instructions from this website:
http://subhra.me/install-postgresql-in-xampp-on-windows-and-integrate-phppgadmin/

I tried the following to get phpPgAdmin to work:

1.I extracted the downloaded phppgadmin ZIP to my Xampp folder:
C:\xampp\phppgadmin 
2. I opened the config.inc.php which can be found C:\xampp\phpPgAdmin\conf\ and edited the file as follows:

```
$conf['servers'][0]['host'] = 'localhost';
$conf['servers'][0]['pg_dump_path'] = 'C:\\xampp\\PostgreSQL\\9.5\\bin\\pg_dump.exe';
$conf['servers'][0]['pg_dumpall_path'] = 'C:\\xampp\PostgreSQL\\9.5\\bin\\pg_dumpall.exe';
$conf['extra_login_security'] = false;
```

3.Than I opened the httpd-xampp.conf to be found in c:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf and did the following:

```
Alias /phppgadmin "C:/xampp/phppgadmin/"
<directory "C:/xampp/phppgadmin">
AllowOverride AuthConfig
Require all granted
</directory>
```

Now I`m getting this error message:

> Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be
>   constructors in a future version of PHP; Misc has a deprecated
>   constructor in C:\xampp\phppgadmin\classes\Misc.php on line 8.
>
> 1. {main}() C:\xampp\phppgadmin\index.php:0
> 2. include_once() C:\xampp\phppgadmin\index.php:11
>
> Warning: session_name(): Cannot change session name when headers
>   already sent in C:\xampp\phppgadmin\libraries\lib.inc.php on line 55
>
> 1. {main}() C:\xampp\phppgadmin\index.php:0
> 2. include_once() C:\xampp\phppgadmin\index.php:11
> 3. session_name() C:\xampp\phppgadmin\libraries\lib.inc.php:55
>
> Warning: session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already
>   sent in C:\xampp\phppgadmin\libraries\lib.inc.php on line 56
>
> 1. {main}() C:\xampp\phppgadmin\index.php:0
> 2. include_once() C:\xampp\phppgadmin\index.php:11
> 3. session_start() C:\xampp\phppgadmin\libraries\lib.inc.php:56
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at C:\xampp\phppgadmin\classes\Misc.php:8) in
>   C:\xampp\phppgadmin\classes\Misc.php on line 526
>
> 1. {main}() C:\xampp\phppgadmin\index.php:0
> 2. Misc->printHeader() C:\xampp\phppgadmin\index.php:12
> 3. header() C:\xampp\phppgadmin\classes\Misc.php:526

I`d appreciate some help and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see at https://sourceforge.net/projects/phppgadmin/, the latest updates were made more than five years ago to phpPgAdmin, so it was not yet made compatible to recent PHP versions. Their [bugtracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/phppgadmin/bugs/) lists your problem among others.

There is a fork at https://github.com/ReimuHakurei/phppgadmin which claims to have these problems fixed.